# Liferay login using API/Webservices

Tags: java, api, liferay

I am using Liferay 6.2 CE. We have Liferay web application and now we want to make mobile(android) app for the same.

I will have to provide a login API using which registered user can login from mobile in Liferay web-app. Once user will be logged in he can continue access the website.

Also I need one access token based on that I can validate next api with the provided `access_token`.

Does liferay provide any login API?

Comment: Have you tried Liferay Screens? https://www.liferay.com/de/community/liferay-projects/liferay-screens

Comment: I have gone through the liferay screens but I think  we need to create a project with mobile based sdk and then I have to create whole app. But as I have already website ready in liferay. I have to provide api to mobile developers so they can call directly Liferay API.  Is it possible I can create a api using LoginScreenlet which consume the users email id and password in Liferay project without sdk?

Answer (score 1):

There is no webservice login API in Liferay.

All the Liferay webservice are visible at this url:

- http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws (for json)
- http://localhost:8080/api/axis (for wsdl)

Authentication is made by passing login/password on the url like:

```
wget http://test@liferay.com:test@localhost:8080/api/jsonws/country/get-countries
```

You can also use Basic Authentication by adding header to your request (encode in base64).

If you need another Authentication process you have to develop your own web service. Documentation to do that is here: http://www.liferay.com/fr/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/json-web-services-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-05-en

Sincerely

Comment: Is there any idea using which we can send access_token in api response to users and using this token we can validate user next time?

Comment: I think you have to create a new authentication filter (implements AutoLogin) which can authenticate an user with your "acces_token" data (like BasicAuthHeaderAutoLogin do with an header value).

After that you have to create a webservice which generate an "acces_token" for an user and pass the acces_token in your request.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Let me try with this.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if you consider it the correct one. ;)

Comment: Do you try to create a new AutoLogin filter ?

Comment: Can you edit your message and add your AutoLogin source code as well as your portal-ext.properties please ?

Comment: My wget and curl both complain about that command, it seems like they're interpreting the password "test" as a port. Can you unpack that request into a more verbose curl command, they seem to be easier to read :)